# How to create suggestion messages with ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, interactive

I want to create an interactive version of the ANTLR [calculator example](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/code/tour/basic/Expr.g), which tells the user what to type next. For instance, in the beginning, the `ID`, `INT`, `NEWLINE`, and `WS` tokens are possible. Ignoring `WS`, a suggestion message could be:

`Type an identifier, a number, or newline.`

After parsing a number, the message should be

`Type +, -, *, or newline.`

and so on. How to do this?

**Edit**

What I have tried so far:

```
private void accept(String sentence) {
    ANTLRInputStream is = new ANTLRInputStream(sentence);
    OperationLexer l = new OperationLexer(is);
    CommonTokenStream cts = new CommonTokenStream(l);
    final OperationParser parser = new OperationParser(cts);
    parser.addParseListener(new OperationBaseListener() {
        @Override
        public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
            ATNState state = parser.getATN().states.get(parser.getState());
            System.out.print("RULE " + parser.ruleNames[state.ruleIndex] + " ");
            IntervalSet following = parser.getATN().nextTokens(state, ctx);
            for (Integer token : following.toList()) {
                System.out.print(parser.tokenNames[token] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
    parser.prog();
}
```

prints the right suggestion for the first token, but for all other tokens, it print the current token. I guess capturing the state at `enterEveryRule()` is too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accurately gathering this information in an LL(k) parser, where k>1, requires a thorough understanding of the parser internals. Several years ago, I faced this problem with ANTLR 3, and found the only real solution was so complex that it resulted in me becoming a co-author of ANTLR 4 *specifically* so I could handle this issue.

ANTLR (including ANTLR 4) disambiguates the parse tree during the parsing phase, which means if your grammar is not LL(1) then performing this analysis in the parse tree means you have already lost information necessary to be accurate. You'll need to write your own version of `ParserATNSimulator` (or a custom interpreter which wraps it) which does not lose the information.